# publish web app using iis locally - SCREEN BLANK

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, publish

I followed this guide using Visual Studio to publish my web app using IIS LOCALLY... skipping the database section for now.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Visual studio published successfully, then it automatically opened up a webpage

http://localhost/ExtApplication4/

The problem is the webpage opens up blank on same computer.  I am also attached the dev tools but I don't know what to look for to see WHY nothing is being displayed.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: register asp.net in the IIS using command "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i"

Comment: just tried that and says FINISHED INSTALLED ASP.NET, but still same error message

Comment: actually the error message did change a bit.  I attached the image above

Comment: go to programs and features in the control panel and make sure you have asp.net selected under Internet Information Services.

Comment: Yes I previously did that already

Comment: And don't forget to set a start up page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123881/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-solarissf).

Comment: How do I set startup page?  Which file do I choose?

Comment: Set default controller and action in your RouteConfig.cs file.

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

Comment: Did you tried adding those tags in web.config?

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33000926#33000926

Comment: thanks!  I had to add mime type .json and appcache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register different file extenstions (mime type) in web.config:

For Example:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.webServer> 
      <staticContent> 
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".appcache" mimeType="text/javascript" /> 
      </staticContent> 
   </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```